# Freebsd write access to group directory

Tags: permissions, group-policy, freebsd

I'm confused.
I have two users in system: u1 and u2, and group u1.
both u1 and u2 belong to u1.
I've created directory /opt/d with properties:

`drwxrwxr-x  2 u1    u1      512B May 26 17:55 d`

AFAIK, this configuration allows both users write to directory.
But, from u2:

`touch /opt/d/x`

`touch: /opt/d/x: Permission denied`

And same configuration on RHEL5 works fine.

What i've missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does u2 have read permissions to all directories above the group directory? If he doesn't have read rights to every directory above he won't be able to get to the group directory which would lead to that error.

Also-have you logged u2 out since you made the changes to the groups? Group membership is only read at login.